# Making a field both foreign and primary key in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a database and in one of the tables, a field should both be a primary and a foreign key. I am new to Django, and I couldn't find an example implementation.

I appreciate all the help,
Didem

I tried looking the documentation or some example repos but didn't see anything

Comment: A `ForeignKey` to what?

Answer (score 0):

Since a primary key is always unique, the `ForeignKey` is then a [**`OneToOneField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField), so:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass


class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this is also how Django emulates *inheritance*. Indeed, with concrete inheritance it automatically adds a hidden primary key that is a `OneToOneField` to the parent model.

Comment: this is Parent Child relationship. isn't it better to extend Bar with Foo

`class Bar(Foo)`

Comment: @AzmatKarimKhan: well that is discussed at the bottom, but given I understand it correctly, the modeling is done for an *existing* database, so then we need control over the database column name.

Comment: yes agreed, it totally depend on your usecase